# How can I dynamically render images from my images folder using Jinja and Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask to learn Python and to create a toy application that I've wanted to make for awhile. I'm having problems with a particular feature which is the standard file uploading. What I want to do is to try to dynamically render an image from my images folder based on a particular model but I seem to be having a problem trying to string interpolate.

Here is my view code:

```
<h1>List of Employees</h1>

{% if employees %}
    {% for employee in employees: %}
      <p>{{ employee.name }}</p>
      <p>{{ employee.title }}</p>
      <p>{{ employee.email }}</p>
      <p>{{ employee.department }}</p>

      # How do I use Jinja and python to interpolate this so I can 
      # grab the correct image
      <img src="static/images/" + {{employee.profile_image }} alt={{ employee.name }} width="120" height="90">{{ employee.profile_image }}</img>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

It should be very straightforward. I have been spoiled by ruby and rails.... Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `{{employee.profile_image}}` be inside the quotes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your `img` tag should look like this

```
<img src="static/images/{{ employee.profile_image }}" alt={{ employee.name }} width="120" height="90" />
```

Assuming `employee.profile_image` is the path relative to `static/images/`

If there is no `profile_image` value but you want to show a default, you can also use Jinja2's `default` filter like so.

```
<img src="static/images/{{ employee.profile_image | default('profile.jpg') }}" alt={{ employee.name }} width="120" height="90" />
```

Comment: Hey grotewold, thanks for the answer but this doesn't seem to resolve my issue. When I hard code the path such as "static/images/profile.jpg" it works just fine. However when I try your answer and check out Chrome developer tools, the employee.profile_image portion is missing.

Comment: If I place the code as you answered above, I'm left with src="static/images/"

Comment: What is `employee.profile_image`? what is an example? The issue you are describing now means there is no data in the `profile_image` property.

Comment: Yes you're right. The image that I am trying to upload is not being saved into my database. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I also added info about the `default` Jinja filter for you as well. Will be helpful for people without uploaded pictures.

Comment: Thanks grotewold. I appreciate it and I got the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

- Your `images` folder is located inside the `static` folder
- You only store full file_name and not the path inside `employee.profile_image`

You can use following alternative to load images to Jinja2 template:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'images/'+employee.profile_image) }}" alt="">
```

(**Notice** that there is no `{}` arround `employee.profile_image`.)

The difference between this method and the other is that when you try to load your image from let's say `employees/employee_details.html` template, you get the correct path for your image: `/static/images/employee_image_1.jpg`.

But if you try to do the same with `<img src="static/images/{{ employee.profile_image }}" alt="" />`, your path can end up being: `/employees/static/images/employee_image_1.jpg` which is not what you want.